# Istio on Azure Container Service (AKS)

Tags: azure-container-service, istio

I was planning on installing Istio on my new AKS cluster. However, in the prerequisites for Istio, it is mentioned that K8S cluster should have RBAC enabled. However, I read that AKS ( preview ) doesn't have it enabled. Is this true? Is there an option for me to try Istio on AKS.

Comment: You can vote for RBAC implementation in Azure AKS here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/32855575-implement-rbac-authorization-for-kubernetes-in-aks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact RBAC is not available in Azure AKS currently. According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/67) it is on the roadmap for Q1 2018.

In Azure you can use [ACS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-walkthrough) which is an older version of AKS, but with control over Kubernetes master or [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine) where you have full control over Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 5):

AKS is GA and looks like RBAC is available now,
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-kubernetes-service-aks-ga-new-regions-new-features-new-productivity/

Answer (score 0):

AKS now enables `RBAC` by default.

There are also docs on how to install Istio:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/istio-install

Answer (score 0):

We are doing POC for service mesh on our AKS cluster using istio. I have found a very good guide to install istio with all its components on AKS cluster and it does not require any RBAC on AKS. Infact this guide is cloud agnostic. I am not sure if it production graded ready but working like a charm till now. Just apply first 3 files and 4th one optional. The name might be little confusing for you. But its working on AKS very well. Hope that worsk for you.

[Istio Installation Files](https://github.com/DickChesterwood/istio-fleetman/tree/master/_course_files/warmup-exercise)

```
kubectl apply -f 1-istio-init.yaml 2-istio-minikube.yaml 3-kiali-secret.yaml
```